# JQuery event suppression

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input box, and I have bound both `blur` and `keypress` events to the input, but the problem is when there is a `keypress` event, `blur` event also fires. Is there any way to suppress the `blur` event when `keypress` event occurs?

Comment: It'd help if you posted an example of your code. I don't think blur should be firing from keypress unless your keypress handler is actually causing the element to lose focus.

Comment: Don't use the keypress event, use the keyup event instead (better supported)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like something in your EventHandlerKeyPress() function is raising a blur.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code a little just to test and couldn't come to the same conclusion about the order of events firing. Firebug's console shows the following code execution yielding .keypress always occuring before a .blur

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#inpt").blur(function(e) {
            console.log(".blur");
        });

        $("#inpt").keypress(function(e) {
            console.log(".keypress");
        });
    });

</script>
```

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with .onchange, and .keypress bound to the same field? Might help if you posted your event handler code as well.

Also, you have a global document.keypress bound as well, any particular reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#inpt").blur(function(e) {
            EventHandlerBlur(e);
        });
       $("#inpt").keypress(function(e) {
              EventHandlerKeyPress(e);
          });

          $(document).keypress(function(e) {
              EventHandlerKeyPress(e);
          });


    });
</script>
```

here is the code with same behavior. actually on entering on input/ or even pressing any key on input box is causing blur event to fire first before the keypress event..